# User profile in isomorphic applications

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication, isomorphic-javascript

I'm currently in the process of adding login, plus a set of advanced features related to login, to a website using React, Redux, Express and Node. For the actual login, I'm using Passport, with Facebook, Google and Twitter strategies. After getting the required token, it's sent to AWS Cognito Federated Identities to get synchronized data for the user. Data from the website is also synchronized back to Cognito whenever needed.

After the user has logged in, I can construct a complete user profile on the Node server, but now what?

```
// server.jsx
// imports
.............

// variables
.............

var userProfile;
// logging the user with Passport and adding it to the profile
.............

app.use((req, res) => {
    // I can do whatever I want with the profile here
    .............

    // handling the request and creating an initial state ..
    .............
}
```

Back in the days, this would be fairly easy to solve using either session variables (Java/C#) or cookies (JS), but in isomorphic applications it's not quite that simple. Let's say that the user gets access to profile.jsx via routes after logging in: A cookie (set via client-sessions for example) is only available when the jsx file is run on the client; it's not accessible whenever it's server rendered.

Custom code appears to be required even when using things like isomorphic-cookie or universal-cookie, which pretty much defeats the purpose of an isomorphic application. I also thought of using Redux, but Redux appears to only have an initial state on Node, which doesn't help much.

```
// Profile.jsx
import React , { Component } from 'react';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

class Profile extends Component {
    // Stuff
    .............

    render() {
        // Would love to be able to access to the profile without custom code like this
        if (typeof window != 'undefined' && window.document) {
            const cookies = new Cookies();
            console.log(cookies.get('user'));
        }
    }
```

So is there a smooth way of handling user profiles or other variables that you want access to at all times, without writing a huge amount of custom code for each scenario? It seems most tutorials and examples handle this sort of thing exclusively either on the server or the client, which would require a re-write of the website in this particular case.

Isomorphic applications are fairly straight forward in most cases, but the complexity really shoots through the roof when authentication, profiles and so on is introduced, so I would greatly appreciate any feedback on the matter.

Comment: There are frameworks that support isomorphic apps, as far as I know express isn't one of them

Comment: you may look at meteor.js for writing such apps(it can work with react)

Comment: The website is already in production, and has been for a year. It's an express/node-based isomorphic application, so I'm not sure I understand what you mean.. ?

Comment: sorry didn't know the website is in production, anyway what I meant is to look at this :

Comment: https://www.meteor.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think a common scenario here would be to add an authentication step, then to store a successful authentication token either as a cookie or in your app state that you supply back to the profile API on subsequent queries.

Any data that is returned form your API can also be added to your Redux store so you always have access to it and subsequently updated whenever you need to persist changes or want to force update the current state data.

Comment: Right, we already have the token, stored in a cookie (Passport -> Client-Sessions -> stored in a cookie called "user"). This cookie is being sent with each request, so the back-end always has access to it.

Comment: What I essentially want to do is access session-based data in various jsx files without custom code (client vs server). The Redux store might be an option, as we already use needs = []; to get data from an API, but this situation is different in that I would have to pass the token to the actions, and then access Cognito from the actions.

That still leaves me with the problem of reading and passing the token in an isomorphic way. Any ideas? Or perhaps ideas for a different approach?